# $4^{x}+2^{x+1}=18$ Please help me solve?

Tags: calculus, exponentiation

I tried using logs on both sides or tried treating it as a quadratic but didn't manage to simplify it, Help?:D

Comment: Please include your prior work in your question to provide context and details. For instance, what variable did you use when trying to solve as a quadratic?

Comment: Hint: $4=2^2$ so $4^x=(2^2)^x$

Comment: Are you just trying to simplify or solve for x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Let $t=2^x>0$. Then the equation becomes $$t^2+2t-18=0.$$

So $t=-1+\sqrt{19}$. $t\not=-1-\sqrt{19}$ Since $t>0$.

So $x=\log_2(-1+\sqrt{19})$.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Let $x = \log_2(y)$, and rewrite your equation as $$(2^x)^2+2(2^x)-18=0$$

Comment: Ive done that, But it makes it have a realllly ugly answer D:, Because you have to use the quadratic equation and then that just gets me 2^x, so then i have to get the log of both sides. But i just need confirmation if thats the right path to take

Comment: If you make the substitution I suggested, what do you get for $y$?

Comment: 2^x=y=(-2+-sqrt(76))/2  Sb already mentioned the answer, Thanks though, appreciate the time

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $4^x=(2^2)^x=2^{2x}$. This can easily be reduced to a quadratic equation via a neat substitution.

Comment: I guess i know what you mean, using(2^x)^2, But that ends up making me use the equation: 2^x=(-2+-sqrt(76))/2

Answer (score -1):

$$(2^x)^2+2\cdot (2^x)-18=0$$

Same as $x^2+2x-18=0$ (after substitution).

Use the quadratic formula to find the roots. Set a root equal to $2^x$ then do the log.